# How to disable double click event on radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button

I just want to disable double click event on my radio button, that's it. I don't really know how to achieve that.
See my radio button is already inside radio group, I have custom it like this: when I click on it, it expand a dropdown, when I click again it collapse the dropdown, but when I double click on it while the list is expanded, the list collapse in but the radio button active, so I totally want to disable the double click event only.

Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: You wanna click just unique time? Use RadioGroup instead!

Comment: What is "not work in a correct way"?

Comment: oh when I double click on radio button when the list is already expand, the list collapse in but the radio button active.

Comment: Post your code here

Answer (score 3):

I found to solve this common problem,

If you want to call prevent two click from `XML` file then write below code,

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:onClick="preventTwoClick"/>
```

If you want to call prevent two click from `JAVA` file then write below code,

```
radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Prevent Two Click
        preventTwoClick(view);
        // Do magic
    }
});
```

And in another function like,

```
public void preventTwoClick(final View view){
    view.setEnabled(false);
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           view.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I already try your solution, but it seem difference scenario. My radio button is already inside radio group, I have custom it like this: when I click on it, it expand a dropdown, when I click again it collapse the dropdown, but when I double click on it while it is expanded it does not work in a correct way, so I totally want to disable the double click event only.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation

> To create each radio button option, create a RadioButton in your
>   layout. However, because radio buttons are mutually exclusive, you
>   must group them together inside a RadioGroup. By grouping them
>   together, the system ensures that only one radio button can be
>   selected at a time.

Then use like follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Each `RadioButton` will be clicked unique time, avoiding the double click!

Comment: My radio button is already inside radio group, I have custom it like this: when I click on it, it expand a dropdown, when I click again it collapse the dropdown, but when I double click on it while it is expanded it does not work in a correct way, so I totally want to disable the double click event only.